# How can multiple threads (parallel testcases) access same excel file at same time using Apache POI in Java (Selenium) setup?

Tags: java, excel, multithreading, selenium, apache-poi

I have few data dependent testing scenarios where I have one Excel file as data source and multiple testcases needs to be executed from that file concurrently.

I already have prepared a solution where I can run 1 test at a time. But when I try to run multiple tests, Apache is throwing up error. I think that is because multiple threads are trying to access same resource at same time. How to overcome this situation? My solution using Apache-POI libraries in Java for Selenium testing.

*Edit:*

**Error Message:**  org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.OpenXML4JRuntimeException: Fail to save: an error occurs while saving the package : The part /xl/media/image13.png failed to be saved in the stream with marshaller org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.marshallers.DefaultMarshaller@329cf141

**OS:** Windows 10, x64

**Code:** 
**Step 1:** Creating a Workbook object as below

```
Workbook wb = null;
        try {
            wb = WorkbookFactory.create(input_file);
        } catch (java.io.FileNotFoundException e) {
            Results.fail("Excel file not found at this location: " + Excel_File_Name_And_Path);
        }
```

**Step 2:** Iterate through all the rows one by one and save relevant information into various Java variables

**Step 3:** Close the Workbook object and proceed with testing (having all relevant data now)

```
ExcelConfiguration.closeworkbook(wb);

    public static void closeworkbook(Workbook wb) {

            try {
                wb.close();

                System.out.println("workbook closed");

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            } catch (IOException ioexcep) {

                ioexcep.printStackTrace();

            }
        }
```

Comment: I don't know POI enough to know why it cannot read the same file concurrently. But you can share the "reader" or just copy the file temporarily to read it..

Comment: What's the error? What's your code look like? What OS are you on? There isn't enough information in your question to provide a reasonable answer.

Comment: @Brian added comments as requested. Please have a look again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like POI is writing back out to the file when you close it. You can try opening it in read-only mode with a [different `create` call](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/WorkbookFactory.html#create-java.io.File-java.lang.String-boolean-):

```
wb = WorkbookFactory.create(input_file, null, true);
```

This will open the file in read-only mode and should skip the write-on-close behavior.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to dive into POI internals just load it once in a singleton class in `static` initialization block.

If your code is truly read-only there should be no downside as `static` block will get executed just once during class initializaiton.